# A double sequence in a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sequences-and-series

Let $V$ be a infinite dimensional Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{a_{m,n} \cdot v_{m,n}\}_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a double sequence with $a_{m,n} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $v_{m,n} \in V$ such that:
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
(a_{m,n} \cdot v_{m,n})
=
u
$$
and
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:
\lim_{m \to \infty}
v_{m,n}
=
u_0
\neq
0
$$
I would like to know if is it true that $u= a \cdot u_0$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Is it true when $V$ is $1$-dimensional?  If so, can that be used to prove your case?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar $V$ is infinite dimensiona, now i edit

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: If V is 1-dimensional and $u_0\neq 0$, isn't it tautologically true that $u=au_0$ for some a? Don't you mean 2-dimensional rather than 1-dimensional?

Comment: I thing it's true but i can't get the proof... and i need a proof

Comment: I don't think it is true, if $\dim V>1$: given any $u$ and $u_0$ linearly independent, take $a_{n,m}:=\delta_{n,m}$, and $v_{n,n}:=u$ for all $n$  and $v_{m,n}:=u_0$ for $n\neq m$.

Comment: To get the conclusion you wish, i would apply a dominated convergence for series, assuming the needed hypotheses.

Comment: @PietroMajer thanks for your answer and suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer is "No", and the following
counterexample works in each space $V$ which is at least
two-dimensional. Let $u$ and $v$ be linearly independent vectors
in $V$.

We let $\{v_{m,n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence which starts
with $m$ vectors  $u+v$, continues with $m$ vectors $u-v$, and all
further vectors are equal to $0$. Then the limits
$\lim_{m\to\infty}v_{m,n}$ are all equal to $u+v$.

Now let $\{a_{m,n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence which starts with
$2m$ coefficients $\frac1{2m}$ and continues arbitrarily.

It is clear that the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{m,n} \cdot
v_{m,n})$ are all equal to $u$, and hence their limit as
$m\to\infty$ is equal to $u$. Since $u$ and $v$ are linearly
independent, we get the desired example.

Comment: This is very close to [@PietroMajer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288974/a-double-sequence-in-a-banach-space#comment715775_288974)'s comment, I think.

Comment: @LSpice You are right (I just checked the Pietro's comment).